# Could not instantiate FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

I updated the Android Support Library to rev 23.1
Then I'm also not able to find the Class

My Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

in `build.gradle`

Android Design Support Library != Android Support Library

Comment: I am using Android Studio. Any special library android studio needs??

Comment: Add the line above to your `build.gradle` file in Android Studio. You know about `build.gradle` right?

Comment: Done what you said but when i use FloatingActionButton it doesnt give me preview and also doesnt runs on mobile too

Comment: Make sure `layout_width` and `layout_height` are specified

Answer (score 0):

In your projects app/build.gradle add the design library to your dependencies. Don't forget to sync your gradle files after doing so.

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'`

This is a copy and paste from the layout file generated by Android Studio when creating a Blank Activity. You should be able to use it no problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id = "@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity = "bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin = "@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src = "@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

You will need to define `@dimen/fab_margin` in your dimens.xml like so.

`<dimen name = "fab_margin">16dp</dimen>`

Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to add android support design lib . You can find it from maven or write this in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Secondly add the floating button height width gravity and icon like this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" 
/>
```

Comment: This error was shown.The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)